# Visual Studio 2015 Team Explorer Git branches not working properly

Tags: git, visual-studio, github, version-control, visual-studio-2015

I have got access to a private git repository [like git.itabc.com] from my client. The code is on master branch. I am asked to create a new branch each time i start a new task. so I go to Team Explorer and select current branch http://prntscr.com/cmfxtp and click "Create New Local Branch From" and create a branch (which gets checked out and selected). Then I commit the code using Tortoise git ( beacuse when i try to commit/publish branch using Team Explorer publish, I get error

```
"Inner Exception:
    The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly."
```

But when i try to work on another computer, I don't see that new branch untill i clone the code again and mention new branch name in clone settings like this http://prntscr.com/cmfzbl

How can I do all this from visual studio team explorer?

Please suggest.

Comment: This is usually caused by a Anti-Virus with HTTP scanning enabled that does funny things. Or a proxy server.

Comment: i don't have antivirus on my machine.

Comment: Your machine, proxy server, router, tfs server...

Comment: No, nothing from these.

Comment: Connection close is generally a network issue, not something Team Explorer initiates, it's something that the server or the network infrastructure does. Depending on your infrastructure it's also possible that a very slow connection can lead to this behavior. You could try to use Fiddler to see exactly which call fails.

Comment: @jessehouwing fiddler shows this when i did git sync in VS 2015 TFS explorer http://prntscr.com/cmlsza and VS output window shows this "Inner Exception:
    The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly.
Error encountered while pushing to the remote repository: Response status code does not indicate success: 504 (Fiddler - Receive Failure)."

Comment: Looks like the tfs server responded with text/html, can you look at the body if the response?

Comment: @jessehouwing response in fiddler is "Fiddler] ReadResponse() failed: The server did not return a complete response for this request. Server returned 0 bytes.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       "

Comment: Seems that the server or your infrastructure is automatically fault.